# Pandas : How to aggregate hourly count with time start and end

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with start and end time for each unique rating ID.

```
d={'ID':['01','02','03','04','05','06'],'Hour Start':[5,9,13,15,20,23],'Hour End':[6,9,15,19,0,2]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

My goal is to aggregate how many ratings were active hourly for the whole dataset. For example, ID:01 started during 5 am and 6 am. Then 5 am and 6 am should both add 1 count each.

But for ID:06, the rating started in 11 pm and ended next day at 2 am. Hence each hour should add 1 count each hour from 11 pm to 2 am.

I want to output a table for hourly summary like below.

[image]

I have been thinking a while for a solution.

Any help would be very appreciated ! Thank you !

Comment: Good question, but you need to clarify some assumptions. For example: 1. Are both columns guaranteed to be monotonic with respect to the absolute time they represent? 2. When a number in a column is lower than the previous number, is it guaranteed that this means the time exactly one day later?

Comment: @timgeb Thank you for the response. 1. Yes, both columns are. 2. Yes, if the Hour End is lower than Hour Start, it means it ends the next day.

Comment: @C4TNT I see you edited the post, exactly whats the logic behind calculating the hourly summary table?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Sorry that I didn't make it clear enough. Let me try an analogy. I have many slot machines being played each hour. I want to know how many machines were played for each hour. But I have only the time start and time end on each machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert to datetime both the hour start and end columns. Then you compute the difference in time. Finally, you convert the time difference to difference in hours (divide the seconds by 3600):

```
df['Hours_s'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour Start'], format='%H' )
df['Hours_e'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour End'], format='%H' )
df['delta'] = df['Hours_e']-df['Hours_s']
df["count"] = df["delta"].apply(lambda x: x.seconds//3600)
```

Output:

```
ID   Hour_Start Hour_End count
0          5       6       1
1          9       9       0
2          13      15      2
3          15      19      4
4          20      0       4
5          23      2       3
```

**UPDATE:**

```
final_tab = pd.DataFrame({"Hour": range(0,24), "Count": [0]*24})

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row["delta"].days != 0:
        final_tab.iloc[row["Hour Start"]:24,1] =final_tab.iloc[row["Hour Start"]:24,1] +1
        final_tab.iloc[0:row["Hour End"]+1,1] =final_tab.iloc[0:row["Hour End"]+1,1] +1
    else:
        final_tab.iloc[row["Hour Start"]:row["Hour Start"]+row["count"],1] = final_tab.iloc[row["Hour Start"]:row["Hour Start"]+row["count"],1] + 1
```

Output:

```
print(final_tab)
   Hour Count
0   0   2
1   1   1
2   2   1
3   3   0
4   4   0
5   5   1
6   6   1
7   7   0
8   8   0
9   9   1
10  10  0
11  11  0
12  12  0
13  13  1
14  14  1
15  15  2
16  16  1
17  17  1
18  18  1
19  19  1
20  20  1
21  21  1
22  22  1
23  23  2
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can do it like this using `pd.to_datetime` and `pd.date_range`:

```
#Convert hours to datetime
df['endTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour End'], format='%H')
df['startTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Hour Start'], format='%H')

#If 'Hour End' less thn 'Hour Start' assume next day
df['endTime'] = np.where(df['Hour End'] < df['Hour Start'], 
                         df['endTime']+pd.Timedelta(days=1), 
                         df['endTime'])

#Create a series of hours per defined ranges ('Hour Start' to 'Hour End')
df_hourly = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(pd.date_range(x['startTime'], 
                                                       x['endTime'], 
                                                       freq='H')), 
                                         axis=1)\
              .stack().dt.hour

#Use value counts to count the hours and reindex to 24-hour day to fill missing hours.
df_hourly.value_counts().reindex(np.arange(0,24)).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Output:

```
0     2
1     1
2     1
3     0
4     0
5     1
6     1
7     0
8     0
9     1
10    0
11    0
12    0
13    1
14    1
15    2
16    1
17    1
18    1
19    1
20    1
21    1
22    1
23    2
```

Alternatively, using `explode` and `value_counts`:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.date_range(x['startTime'], 
                                 x['endTime'], 
                                 freq='H'), axis=1)\
  .explode().dt.hour.value_counts()\
  .reindex(np.arange(0,24), fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This is what I am trying to output !